# QuerySet object has no attribute user

Tags: python, django

I am having a little problem trying to get list of all my profile users. When I try the code below Django says: QuerySet object has no attribute user

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.Auth)

def home(request):
    p = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
    u = p.user
```

But when I add first() at the end, it only display the first user. List of all users is what I want.

```
def home(request):
    p = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user).first() 
    u = p.user
```

Answer (score 0):

You got error because you are trying to get attribute from queryset here `u = p.user`. 
You can get atribute only from item of queryset `p[0].user` for example.

If you want get list of users you can just filter `User` model directly.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User.objects.exclude(pk=request.user.id)
```

Comment: @weAreStarDust...you are right, but how do I get pass this error?

Comment: Thank you, but why this work but only gets the first user in Profile: def home(request):
    p = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user).first() 
    u = p.user

Comment: @GistDomBlog Because `first()` [Returns the first object matched by the queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#first)